# how to mofify font-size relatively in boostrap col-sm-3

Tags: html, css, font-size

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <!--main content-->
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <ul class="HomeIndex">
          <li>relative sentence</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--main content-->

    <!--sidebar-->
    <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs" style="padding: 0px">

    </div><!--side bar-->
 </div>
```

I'd like to modify the relative sentence in the li. my.css write like

```
.home_index{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2
}
```

i thought the font-size will mofify by the rem, but the font-size keeps same size. i may miss write the code. how to modify the font-size by the width of screen.

please give me suitable code.

Comment: In your HTML, you use the class name "HomeIndex". But your CSS uses the class name "home_index".

Comment: Oh. thanks. It's activated

Answer (score 2):

Simple class mistake:
Your `ul` has a class of HomeIndex, while your styling is `.home_index`. Either change your `ul` class to `home_index`, or your style to `.HomeIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

use `home_index` with your html

```
  <!--main content-->
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <ul class="home_index">
          <li>relative sentence</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--main content-->
```

or

change css class `home_index` to `HomeIndex`